# Android Studio Emulator : Waiting for target device to come online

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So i'm new to android studio and trying to create my own app. But Ive been having trouble running the app on the emulator, where the emulator launches but the app does not and I am stuck at Waiting for target device to come online.

I have the most up to date android studio and have Android Emulator 28.0.2. I have the configuration set to launch with the main activity. I have also tried changing the emulator API level and does not change the situation.

Does anyone know how I would go about fixing this? Also do not have an android phone as an alternative way of testing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've very recently started seeing this nearly every time I compile and run.  Trying again works, but it's a pain to *have* to try again.  Work flow: hit ctrl-r to run, wait while compiles, wait while it tries to load, wait for the load to fail, hit ctr-r again, wait for load to successfully go, and _then_ see the results of my work.  Sigh.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that you checked **Android Emulator** and click **Apply**

[image]

Comment: Yes I do have this checked. Also I am running windows 10 if that helps.

Comment: great! I updated the emulator and build-tools and the problem was disappeared

Answer (score 3):

Whenever the emulator struggles to come online, a **cold boot** often solves the problem regardless of the cause.
Tools -> AVD Manager -> Your emulator -> Cold boot from drop down menu on the right

Answer (score 0):

It means that the emulator is not starting. Try deleting it and creating a new emulator the try again.
Alternatively, go ahead and run the emulator from the AVD manager then run the project itself.

Comment: I've tried many different emulators, and none seem to change anything. I had a friend run it on his samsung phone and it came up in his apps and worked. Although it does not launch and does not show up in the apps on the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. I was using `Android SDK Platform-Tools 29.0.5`, and Android Studio gave me a warning, suggesting that I should update it. So I updated it to the latest version (`29.0.6`), and then the problem was fixed. Perhaps it's just a issue of `Android SDK Platform-Tools`. Hope that helps.